# How to set up a WordPress site locally that was developed by someone else on Gitlab

Tags: wordpress, macos, mamp

I have a website that I designed and did all the frontend dev work. I then handed all my files over to my Wordpress developer. They built out the site and gave me access to the files on Gitlab. What I want to do is set up a local copy of the repo on my Mac (which I have done ), branch it and make some CSS changes to the site. Commit those changes and let the developer merge what I have done. I'm new to WP, so I haven't done much in the way of setting up a site. I've watched a couple of videos, but they all seem to be for someone who needs to download and install a fresh install of WP. I don't think this is what I want to do. I downloaded and installed MAMP, and set up localhost, tried to point it to my local repo on my Mac, but that's not working. I just can't find anything to point me in the right direction. Hoping someone here has some advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you DO need to download and install Wordpress. The files that your developer would have given you would be for a custom theme, you'll need to install wordpress and create a custom theme then direct the theme at your files. Something like that anyway I'm not a Wordpress developer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've already cloned the site to your local and you've made a database in MAMP? And you've named them the same.

From there you should be able to pull up localhost:8888/databaseName and proceed with the WordPress install that you cloned. If this isn't working check to make sure that you cloned the project into the same directory that you specified when you set up MAMP. Still not working, check to see if you also cloned the wp-config.php file. Then go to the wp-config.php file and make sure the database specified is the correct database name and that username and password are "root". Still no? Make sure the table prefixes in the database are the same.

For background - usually when you install a fresh WordPress, the first screen you come to has you set up all this info. And, if you are cloning a project, usually the config file is in .gitignore since it is specific to where you are using it.